# Session Token API SSL Certificate

Tags: python-2.7, session, ssl

```
def session(): #This is trying to get the session toekn programaticly. 
    resp = requests.post('https://identitysso.betfair.com/api/certlogin', data=payload, cert=(Keypathpub, Keypathprivate), headers=headers)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        resp_json = resp.json()
        print resp_json['loginStatus']
        sessionToken = resp_json['sessionToken']
    else:
        print "Request failed."
while s > 0:
    session()
    s = 0
```

This is the code I'm using. (Keypathpub and Keypathprivate) are variables with the location of the file SSL certificates, but it's throwing back this error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 336445442] _ssl.c:365: error:140DC002:SSL              routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:system lib
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
```

How do I fix it?